# will this parallel stream work?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, fork, wait

I am trying to add a parallel processing component to a single thread single process program. I am just learning some of the multi-processing methods and as such am not totally sure of their capabilities.

The program logic I am looking to implement:

- main process calls a function.

  - called function fork()'s at start of a for loop.

    - child continues with function work either performing other sub-functions or exiting back based on time checks.
  - meanwhile, parent ends first for loop round and starts again thus re-forking a second  child.
- function continues until for loop finishes after around 10 fork()'s have been executed.
- function gets called again once completed based on a higher level timer.

Will this implementation work? Example code:

```
check_timer() {
   for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      pid_t pid = fork();
      if(pid == 0) {
         execute child 1 checks and possible executes..
         exit(); // when completed
      }
      else {
         parent maybe does something or just ends first round of for loop..
      }
   }
some implementation of wait(); to wait for all children to finish before leaving check_timer() function..
}
```

Will this create up to 10 child processes at once executing in the background of a parent that then waits for the children to finish? Also some tips on how to use wait() would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will end up with 11 processes in total.

You likely want the `waitpid` function, called until there are no more children (a return of `ECHILD`).

EDIT: just noticed you need `pid_t pid = fork();`, not `pid = pid();`

Comment: Are there specific parameters that I need to pass to waitpid(); or does it just know to wait on the parents children? Also, is the pid check always going to just need to check for 0 value? And will the parent always execute on the else properly?

Comment: @jake `man 2 waitpid`. A `pid` parameter of `-1` means "wait for any child process". You cannot wait on children that aren't your own, so that's not a problem. Yes, the parent will always get a nonzero value for the `fork()` return.

Comment: So it looks like there is no wait for ALL child processes, right? Can I implement a loop counter that waits for any child but waits until all 10 children are done? I really just need to make sure that all children have returned as any open children may cause access problems in the next iteration.

Comment: As I said in my post, loop until you get a return of `-1` and an error status of `ECHILD`.

Comment: So I must loop execution of `waitpid(-1, &status, 0);` and compare `&status` until `ECHILD` is found then I can `exit();` the entire function?

Comment: No, you compare `errno` to `ECHILD`, and you don't want to `exit();`, you want to `return`.

Comment: How do I use errno in this regard? errno(of what?)? Never used errno before and the man page doesn't show any examples. In this program I do want to exit as it shuts down the first process to be restarted again by a higher level timer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7130/discussion-between-borealid-and-jake)